# Reset hidden items from previous search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement search in Javascript for my application, and I'm running into an issue where items I previously hid will not show up again. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/Y5w5r/9/)

My code is here:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $searchproject.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).parents('div.srcprojects').hide();
});
```

The problem is I am hiding the parent srcprojects container of my filtered selection, so keyup doesn't show it again.

However, if I change

```
$searchproject.show().filter(function() {
```

to

```
$searchproject.parents('div.srcprojects').show().filter(function() {
```

it does not work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding

```
$searchproject.parents('div.srcprojects').show();
```

Full code:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $searchproject.parents('div.srcprojects').show();
    $searchproject.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).parents('div.srcprojects').hide();
});
```